# is there a way to internally store all logging history and exporting to a file only when necessary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently designing an application where calling a specific function "export_log" will output all the previous log history regarding user interaction with the app from the start. I initially stored all the logs in lists and then outputted to a file, but I was looking for a better way. I came across the Python logging module which seems perfect for my needs, however I'm a bit unfamiliar regards to getting it to work properly.

Below is my Minimum Working Example. func1 is basically the logger which will output "foo" everytime it is called by func2. At the moment, a blank file is created first time running the script. However running the script a second time appends the file, but this is not expected. I want to store all the previous history of output generated from func1.

What should I do to make sure that export_log function outputs a log file only when it is called on demand?

```py
import logging
global logger
logger = logging.getLogger('log_file')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#
def export_log():
    global logger
    fh = logging.FileHandler('logFile.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

# run 3 times
def func1():
    global logger
    logger.info("foo")

def func2():
    for i in range(3):
        func1()

func2()
export_log()

# Desired output upon calling the export_log() function:
# foo
# foo
# foo

# Actual output:
# File is initially blank after running script once.
# always appends "foo" every time the script is run again
```

**Edit**: 
The `export_log` function is required because it is called by a Tkinter button: `Button(controls, text="Export", command = export_log)`. I basically want to output to file all the log history only when the Button is clicked.

Comment: Wouldn't that waste memory and make your code more complicated by having to call `export_log` all the time?

Comment: `export_log` doesn't write anything; it just opens a file for writing (using append mode, but `logging.FileHandler('logFile.log', mode='w')` would truncate the file first). The idea is to call `export_log` *first*, then call `func2`. I'm not sure why you would want to accumulate log messages in memory first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case a possible solution is to save the data in a `io.StringIO()` and when you press the button save it in a file:

```py
import io
import logging
import shutil

stream = io.StringIO()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)


def export_log():
    handler.flush()
    with open("logFile.log", "w") as fd:
        stream.seek(0)
        shutil.copyfileobj(stream, fd)
# ...
```